# How to create a table where one column contains a same value for all rows with different id?(See Layout for clarity)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

[image: Image showing example report, empty]

In this table score, start date , Completion Date will be same for all error code but will be taken as an input once in the beginning.

Comment: Rows with the same id? All this makes very little sense.

Comment: @jeroen My Bad. Edited it. You can see table layout for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a guess because your question isn't very clear. You are looking for a one-to-many pattern to hold this collection of data.

It looks like you have two entities (in the parlance of [entity-relationship data modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model)).

1. Review
2. Review Error

Review has a one-to-many relationship to Review Error: each review may have zero or more Review Errors associated with it. You showed two in your image, but you should still use the one-to-many relationship.

Your Review entity turns into a table like this

```
review:
   review_id    INT   PK
   type         1=Peer Review, 2= Internal Review
   score        FLOAT?  INT?
   start_date   TIMESTAMP
   end_date     TIMESTAMP
```

Your Review Error entity turns into a table like this

```
review_error_id    INT PK
review_id          INT FK to review table
ordinal            INT   0,1,2 showing order of items in report
error              VARCHAR(255)  
description        VARCHAR(255)
quantity           INT? FLOAT?
```

Then to generate the report hinted at by your example table, you do

```
 SELECT review.type,
        review_error.error,
        review_error.description,
        review_error.quantity
        review.score,
        review.start_date,
        review.end_date
   FROM review
   LEFT JOIN review_error ON review.review_id = review_error.review_id
  ORDER BY review.review_id
           review_error.ordinal
```

You use `LEFT JOIN` because ordinary `JOIN` will suppress `review` rows that have no matching `review_error` rows.

If you want the boxes and column headers shown in your image, you'll need to generate those with a client side program. For example, you can define borders around cells in HTML tables.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. You got my question correctly. I am a beginner so couldn't post a pretty good question. Thanks for the concern but I can generate table like that in HTML only problem was that score had to be common for the full review i.e. Peer or Internal.

Comment: If your scores are "common" as you explain, you may then have three entities: Review, Review Phase (internal, peer), and Review Error.  **Pro tip**: hours spent on data model design save weeks on programming. Learn to use entity-relationship design methodology!

Comment: Thanks because without ERD I think it would have taken me nearly 3-4 days to logic it and code it out.